# Irreducible representations of a semidirect product, proof in Serre

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

Let $H$ and $N$ be groups, where $N$ is abelian. Suppose that $H$ acts on $N$ by automorphisms, and consider the semidirect product $G=H\ltimes N$. I am busy classifying all irreducible representations of $G$, as in Section 8.2 by Serre. Since $H$ acts on $N$, $H$ also acts on the character group $\widehat{N}$ by $(h\cdot\chi)(n)=\chi(\phi_{h^{-1}}(n))$. Let $(\chi_i)_{1\leq i\leq k}$ be representatives of the orbits of the $H$-action. For each $i$, let $H_i$ denote the stabilizer subgroup of $\chi_i$ and define $G_i=H_i\ltimes N$ as a normal subgroup of $G$. The function $\chi_i^\circ:G_i\to\mathbb{C}$ given by $\chi_i^\circ(h,n)=\chi_i(n)$ is a linear representation of $G_i$ since $H_i$ stabilizes $\chi_i$.

Now, let $\rho$ be any irreudcible representation of $H_i$, and define $\tilde{\rho}$ to be the irreducible representation of $G_i$ given by $\rho\circ pr_{H_i}$, where $Pr_{H_i}$ is the natural projection on $H_i$. Then define the representation $\theta_{i,\rho}$ of $G$ by $\theta_{i,\rho}=\text{Ind}_{G_i}^G(\tilde{\rho}\otimes\chi_i^\circ)$. By Mackey's irreducibility criterion, each $\theta_{i,\rho}$ is irreducible. Also, $$
\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{\rho\in S_i}\dim(\theta_{i,\rho})^2=|G|,
$$
where $S_i$ is the set of isomorphism classes of irreducible representations of $H_i$. To know that I have really classified all irreducible representations of $G$, I need to prove that if $\theta_{i,\rho}\cong\theta_{i',\rho'}$, then $i=i'$ and $\rho\cong\rho'$. There is a proof of this in Serre (Proposition 25 $ii$), but I don't understand what is going on. Can anyone explain the proof in more detail?

I also tried to come up with my own proof, but it seems to break down. I tried to use character theory. First, I followed Serre's argument to show that $i=i'$. To show that $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are isomorphic, we show that their characters agree. Let $\chi_{\theta_{i,\rho}}$ and $\chi_{\theta_{i,\rho'}}$ denote the characters of $\theta_{i,\rho}$ and $\theta_{i,\rho'}$. Since these are isomorphic, we know that $\chi_{\theta_{i,\rho}}=\chi_{\theta_{i,\rho'}}.$ Since $G_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, we have that $$
\chi_{\theta_{i,\rho}}(h',n')=\frac{1}{|G_i|}\sum_{(h,n)\in G}\chi_i^\circ\big((h,n)^{-1}(h',n')(h,n)\big)\chi_{\tilde{\rho}}\big((h,n)^{-1}(h',n')(h,n)\big)=\frac{1}{|G_i|}\sum_{(h,n)\in G}\chi_i^\circ\big((h,n)^{-1}(h',n')(h,n)\big)\chi_{\rho}(hh'h^{-1})$$
 and 
$$
\chi_{\theta_{i,\rho'}}(h',n')=\frac{1}{|G_i|}\sum_{(h,n)\in G}\chi_i^\circ\big((h,n)^{-1}(h',n')(h,n)\big)\chi_{\tilde{\rho}'}\big((h,n)^{-1}(h',n')(h,n)\big)=\frac{1}{|G_i|}\sum_{(h,n)\in G}\chi_i^\circ\big((h,n)^{-1}(h',n')(h,n)\big)\chi_{\rho'}(hh'h^{-1})
$$
I am stuck on what to do next, since I can't simply simplify $\chi_\rho(hh'h^{-1})=\chi_\rho(h')$. Thanks in advance for the time

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what is going on in your proof, but... can't you use that characters are invariant on conjugacy classes to simplify that?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible since $\chi_\rho$ is a character of $H_i$

Comment: It's not true in general that $G_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. I think you would do better to try and understand the proof in the book.

Comment: It is true in this case, however. Since $H_i$ stabilizes $\chi_i$, we get that $(hh_ih^{-1})\cdot\chi_i=\chi_i$ hence $(h,n)(H_i\ltimes N)(h,n)^{-1}=H_i\ltimes N$

Comment: It is not true that $(hh_ih^{-1})\cdot \chi_i = \chi_i$. The $\chi_i$ are orbit representatives of the action, and you might get a different character in the orbit. For example in the group $S_4$ written as a semidirect product $S_3 \ltimes N$ with $|N|=4$, there are three nontrivial characters of $N$ all in the same $H$-orbit, with stabilizers $H_i$ of order $2$, and $G_i = C_2 \ltimes N$, which are not normal in $S_4$.

Comment: Then what is wrong with the following? $(hh_ih^{-1})\cdot\chi _i(n)=hh_i\cdot\chi_i(\phi_h(n))=h\cdot\chi_i(\phi_h(n))=\chi_i(n)$?

Comment: I don't think that equation makes much sense. The group $H$ is acting on the characters of $N$, not on $N$ itself,, so we are considering the  action of the character $(hh_ih^{-1})\cdot \chi = (h \cdot (h_i  \cdot (h^{-1} \cdot \chi)))$ on elements of $N$.

Comment: Yes I agree. Now $(h\cdot (h_i\cdot(h^{-1}\cdot\chi_i)))(n)=(h\cdot(h_i\cdot\chi_i))(\phi_h(n))=(h\cdot \chi_i)(\phi_h(n))=\chi_i(n)$, since $(h_i\cdot\chi_i)(\phi_h(n))=\chi_i(\phi_h(n))$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this answer I will try to explain in details the proof of 
Proposition 25 in Serre's book. For my convenience in writing this, 
I will use Serre's notation so my $A$ is your $N$, i.e.
$G=H\ltimes A$ and $G_i=H_i\ltimes A$ where $H_i=\{h\in H:h\chi_i=\chi_i\}$
subgroup of $H$.

> (Serre) The restriction of $\theta_{i,\rho}$ to $A$ only 
>   involves characters $\chi$ belonging to the orbit $H\chi_i$
>   of $\chi_i$. This shows that $\theta_{i,\rho}$ determines $i$.

As the statement said, we consider character $\chi$ of $\theta_{i,\rho}$
for $a\in A$. Recall the character for induced representation for $s\in G$,
$H$ subgroup of $G$, $f:H\to \mathbf{C}^{\times}$, is
$$\text{Ind}_H^G(f)(s)=f'(s)=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{t\in G, t^{-1}st\in H}f(t^{-1}st)$$
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
\chi(a) & = \frac{1}{|G_i|}\sum_{t\in G, t^{-1}at\in G_i}
\chi_{\chi_i\otimes \tilde{\rho}}(t^{-1}at), \\
& = \frac{1}{|G_i|}\sum_{t\in G} \chi_i(t^{-1}at)\chi_{\tilde{\rho}}(t^{-1}at), 
\; (A \text{ normal so }  t^{-1}at\in A\subset G_i \; \forall t\in G), \\
& = \frac{\text{dim }V}{|G_i|}\sum_{t\in G}\chi_i(t^{-1}at), \; 
(t^{-1}at\in A \Rightarrow \tilde{\rho}(t^{-1}at)=\rho(1)=\text{id}_V), \\
& = \frac{\text{dim }V}{|G_i|} \sum_{a'\in A,h\in H}\chi_i((a'h)^{-1}a(a'h)),\\
& = \frac{\text{dim }V}{|G_i|} \sum_{a'\in A,h\in H} \chi_i(h^{-1}ah), \; 
(A \text{ abelian}) \\
& = \frac{|A|\text{dim }V}{|G_i|} \sum_{h\in H} (h\chi_i)(a).
\end{align*}
Note that $h\chi_i\in X=\text{Hom}(A,\mathbf{C}^{\times})$ is 
an irreducible representation of $A$ so the above implies that 
the restriction of $\theta_{i,\rho}$ to $A$ is the direct sum of 
representations corresponding to $h\chi_i$. Note that $h\chi_i$'s lie 
in the orbit $H\chi_i\subset X$, which is disjoint with $H\chi_{i'}$
for $i\ne i'$. Hence, if $i\ne i'$, the restriction of $\theta_{i,\rho}$
and $\theta_{i',\rho'}$ to $A$ are not isomorphic.

> (Serre) Let $W$ be the representation space for $\theta_{i,\rho}$, let 
>   $W_i$ be the subspace of $W$ corresponding to $\chi_i$ [the set 
>   of $x\in W$ such that $\theta_{i,\rho}(a)x=\chi_i(a)x$ for all 
>   $a\in A$]. The subspace $W_i$ is stable under $H_i$ and the representation
>   of $H_i$ in $W_i$ is isomorphic to $\rho$; whence $\theta_{i,\rho}$
>   determines $\rho$.

Recall from $\S 7.1$ of Serre's book, $W$ can be identified with 
$W=\mathbf{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbf{C}[G_i]}V$ where 
$V$ is the representation space of $\chi_i\otimes \tilde{\rho}$.
In particular, this is a $\mathbf{C}[G]$-module where $g$ acts 
on $g'\otimes v$ by $(gg')\otimes v$. Also note that, 
$(gg_i)\otimes v$ and $g\otimes (\chi_i\otimes \tilde{\rho})(g_i)v$
are considered the same in $W$ for $g_i\in G_i$.

Now, we identify $W_i$. For $a\in A, g\otimes v\in W$, we have 
$\theta_{i,\rho}(a)(g\otimes v)= (ag)\otimes v
= g \otimes (g^{-1}ag)v$. Since $g^{-1}ag\in A$ so 
$(\chi_i\otimes \tilde{\rho})(g^{-1}ag)v=\chi_i(g^{-1}ag)v$.
Thus, $\theta_{i,\rho}(a)(g\otimes v)= \chi_i(g^{-1}ag)
(g\otimes v)$. Thus, in order for 
$\theta_{i,\rho}(a)(g\otimes v)=\chi_i(a)(g\otimes v)$ for all 
$a\in A$, we must have $\chi_i(a)=(g\chi_i)(a)$ for all $a\in A$.
This follows $g\in H_i$. Thus, $W_i=\mathbf{C}[H_i]
\otimes_{\mathbf{C}[G_i]} V$.

With this, it is obvious that $W_i$ is stable under $H_i$. 
Furthermore, observe $W_i$ is spanned by $1\otimes v_j$
where $v_j$'s basis of $V$, $1$ identity in $H_i$ (this holds
since $h\otimes v=1\otimes \rho(h)v$ for all $h\in H_i,v\in V$). 
Hence, one can easily construct isomorphism representation of 
$H_i$ in $W$ to $\rho$, as desired.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something about the second part of your answer, but it's not enough naively to check this just for a pure tensor element $g \otimes v$. Instead, if you note your computation above with the restriction to $A$, you determine exactly the how much $\chi_i$ appears in the induced, and it's the correct amount ($dim \ro$) to be the trivial element.