# Irreducible real representations of $D_{2k}$ and $(C_{i}\times C_{j})\rtimes D_{2k}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, semidirect-product, computational-algebra

I am considering finite groups of types $D_{2k}$ or $(C_{i}\times C_{j})\rtimes D_{2k}$. I would like to find the irreps of these groups over $\mathbb{R}$ on vector spaces of dimensions $N \lesssim 20$, for which I have bases that that, apart from the trivial irrep, carry the natural representation of $S_N$ in $N-1$ dimensions. Is there a theoretical approach I can follow, or barring that, a practical *computational* approach, preferably implementable in Mathematica, with a focus on ease of implementation rather than optimality.

Comment: There are existing functions in GAP and Magma for finding the complex representations. This problem is difficult and the algorithms involved are complicated.

Comment: I have significantly updated my question, as I had overlooked that much more is in fact known about the structure of the groups involved.

Comment: The representations of the dihedral groups are easy and well understood. They all have dimension $1$ or $2$, and the $2$-dimensionals are as rotation and reflection matrices. I don't know about the other examples. You haven't specified an action for the semidirect product.

Comment: Given the, indeed straightforward answer to the question on $D_{2k}$, I have now sharpened the question considerably. I am mulling on your question about the action in the semidirect product.

Comment: Please don't do that, @BeMuSeD. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Sorry @Shaun, but I was confused about the etiquette here. Should I retract this question, and start over afresh?

Comment: It's okay. As long as you include a link to this question in the new one and explain why you're asking again, I think you'll be fine if you leave this one untouched. You could always ask for further guidance on the meta site.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the requirement of reality, the question I asked is actually an example of a more general fully solved case, namely that of the irreps over $\mathbb{C}$ of the semidirect product $G = A \rtimes_{\varphi} H$, where $A$ abelian, $H$ a group with a known full set of irreps, and $\varphi:H\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(A)$ a homomorphism in $H$ under composition. This case is e.g. treated by Serre, *Linear representations of Finite Groups*, in section 8.2. Let $X=\{\chi_1,\chi_2,\ldots,\chi_{|A|}\}$ be the group of characters of $A$. Define the action of $H$ on this group through $h\chi_i(a)=\chi_i\left(\varphi^{-1}(h)a\right)$. Denote the orbits of $H$ on $X$ as $X_\alpha$, and choose a representative $\chi_\alpha \in X_\alpha$. Let $H_\alpha$ be the stabilizer in $H$ of $\chi_\alpha$, and $\rho_\alpha:H_\alpha\rightarrow V_\alpha$ and irrep of $H_\alpha$. Then $\chi_\alpha \otimes V_\alpha$ carries an irrep of $G_\alpha=A \rtimes_{\varphi} H_\alpha$. Finally, consider the induced representation $\operatorname{Ind}^{G}_{G_\alpha}(\chi_\alpha \otimes V_\alpha)$. The statement is that the latter is irreducible, and that by this procedure all irreps are found. This has been discussed in more detail e.g. in [Irreducible representations of a semidirect product, proof in Serre](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442566/irreducible-representations-of-a-semidirect-product-proof-in-serre). I am confident, but admittedly lack proof, that the requested real irreps can be derived from the complex ones, through standard procedures (see e.g. [Easy way to get real irreducible characters (reps) from complex irreducible characters?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818543/easy-way-to-get-real-irreducible-characters-reps-from-complex-irreducible-char)).